# Is there a way to select a dictionary, and then select a single function from that dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to choose a dictionary via user input, and from there choose a function listed in the chosen dictionary to run. What currently happens with my code is it will correctly pick the right dictionary, but when picking the  function, it will work when inputting the desired function id, but repeat for every item entry in the chosen dictionary. What do I need to do to fix this issue?

The actually functions defined are just printing a random number as a placeholder while testing/debugging. Also I am leaving the functions in their hex memory location for simplicity while testing/debugging.

```
calculus = {
  '1': cal1,
  '2': cal2,
  '3': cal3,
  }
physics = {
  '1': phy1,
  '2': phy2,
  '3': phy3,
  }

def Main():
  a = input("Choose equation set. Calculus or Physics: ")
  if a == "Calculus":
    for item in (calculus.keys()):
      print(item,":",calculus.get(item,'-'))
      eq_id = input("Enter desired equation function id: ")
      eq_arg = input("Press Enter")
      calculus[eq_id](eq_arg)
  elif a == "Physics":
    for item in (physics.keys()):
      print(item,":",physics.get(item,'-'))
      ph_id = input("Enter desired equation id: ")
      ph_arg = input("Press Enter")
      physics[ph_id](ph_arg)
```

Here is an example of what the output gives me: (User input in " ", name of function in ' ', output in '" "')

Choose equation set. Calculus or Physics: "Physics"
1 : (function phy1 at 0x7f32a527c6a8)
Enter desired equation id: "1"
Press Enter
'"347"'
2 : (function phy2 at 0x7f32a527c730)
Enter desired equation id: "3"
Press Enter
'"540"'
3 : (function phy3 at 0x7f32a527c7b8)
Enter desired equation id: "2"
Press Enter
'"429"'

But I want it to be more like this:

Choose equation set. Calculus or Physics: "Physics"
1: 'Physics 1'
2: 'Physics 2'
3: 'Physics 3'
Enter desired equation id: "2"
'"Executes chosen function"'

Comment: You want to loop over your functions first to print their names (not the function objects themselves). I don't see anywhere you are doing that. After that selection is done.

Comment: How about having nested dictionaries instead? `{"calculus": {"1" : cal1, "2" : cal2 ...}, "physics": {"1" : phy1, "2" : phy2 ...}}` something like that, you can turn user input of subject into lowercase to make it easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
def cal1():
    print ("Cal1")

def cal2():
    print ("Cal2")

def cal3():
    print ("Cal3")

def phy1():
    print ("phy1")

def phy2():
    print ("phy2")

def phy3():
    print ("phy3")

calculus = {
  1: cal1,
  2: cal2,
  3: cal3,
  }
physics = {
  1: phy1,
  2: phy2,
  3: phy3,
  }

def main():
    a = input("Choose equation set. Calculus or Physics: ")
    if a == "Calculus":
        for item in calculus.keys():
            print(item,":",calculus[item].__name__)
        eq_id = input("Enter desired equation function id: ")
        calculus[eq_id]()

    elif a == "Physics":
        for item in physics.keys():
            print(item,":",physics[item].__name__)
        ph_id = input("Enter desired equation id: ")
        physics[ph_id]()

main()
```

**Output:**

```
Choose equation set. Calculus or Physics: "Calculus"
(1, ':', 'cal1')
(2, ':', 'cal2')
(3, ':', 'cal3')
Enter desired equation function id: 1
Cal1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you would want in here is a nested dictionary, where the top level keys are "Physics" and "Calculus", and then the values of each would be the dictionaries you already specified.

```
formulas = { "Calculus" : 
               {
                   '1': cal1,
                   '2': cal2,
                   '3': cal3,
                },
             "Physics" : 
                {
                   '1': phy1,
                   '2': phy2,
                   '3': phy3,
                }
           }
```

This way you can do all your input within the same function.

```
a = input("Choose equation set. Calculus or Physics: ")
formula_set = forumlas[a]
for key in forumla_set.keys():
  print("{}: {} {}".format(key, a, key)

eq_id = input("Enter desired equation function id: ")
eq_arg = input("Press Enter")
formula_set[eq_id](eq_arg)
```

And as one of the comments mentioned, might be best to make the dictionary keys lowercase and then convert all input to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be, the following:

```
calculus = {
  '1': calculus_1,
  '2': calculus_2,
  '3': calculus_3,
  }
physics = {
  '1': physics_1,
  '2': physics_2,
  '3': physcis_3,
  }

def Main():
  a = input("Choose equation set. Calculus or Physics: ")
  if a == "Calculus":
    for item in (calculus.keys()):
      # I'm using the __name__ attribute on the function handle
      print(item,":",calculus.get(item,'-').__name__)
      eq_id = input("Enter desired equation function id: ")
      eq_arg = input("Press Enter")
      calculus[eq_id](eq_arg)
  elif a == "Physics":
    for item in (physics.keys()):
      print(item,":",physics.get(item,'-').__name__) # i'm using the __name__ attribute on the function handle
      ph_id = input("Enter desired equation id: ")
      ph_arg = input("Press Enter")
      physics[ph_id](ph_arg)
```

But i suggest, you change the data structure to something like the following;

```
calculus = {
      '1': {
             'func_name': 'calculus 1',
             'func': calculus_1 # where calculus_1 is the function handle
           },
      '2': {
                 'func_name': 'calculus 2',
                 'func': calculus_2 # where calculus_2 is the function handle
               },
      '3': {
                 'func_name': 'calculus 3',
                 'func': calculus_3 # where calculus_3 is the function handle
          }
    }
```

And access it by, something like,

```
for item in (calculus.keys()):
    print(item,":",calculus.get(item,'-')['func_name'])
    ...
    calculus[eq_id]['func'](eq_arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a nested dictionary with the function names:

```
calculus = {
  '1': {'Name': 'Calculus 1', 'Function': cal1},
  '2': {'Name': 'Calculus 2', 'Function': cal2},
  '3': {'Name': 'Calculus 3', 'Function': cal3}
  }
```

And then modify your loop:

```
for key, item in calculus.items():
  print(key,":", item.get('Name'))
eq_id = input("Enter desired equation function id: ")
# eq_arg = input("Press Enter") # <--- (You don't need this)
calculus.get(key).get('Function')()
```

You can also use nested `list`s instead like `['Calculus 1', cal1]` but it might be harder to tell that `calculus['1'][0]` is the name and `calculus['1'][1]` is the function.

If all you care about is a generic function name that increment based on the order it appears, then it's even simpler:

```
for item in (calculus.keys()):
  print(item,":", 'Calculus {}'.format(item)))
  eq_id = input("Enter desired equation function id: ")
  calculus.get(eq_id)()
```